# Recursive function that simulates a non-deterministic finite state machine

Tags: python-2.7, recursion

I have a question about the recursive function below. Given a dictionary

```
edges = { (1, 'a') : [2, 3],
          (2, 'a') : [2],
          (3, 'b') : [4, 2],
          (4, 'c') : [5] }
```

and an accepting state

```
accepting = [5]
```

this function finds a valid path through the FSM:

```
def nfsmaccepts(current, edges, accepting, visited): 
    # base case
    if current in visited:
        return None
    elif current in accepting:
        return ""
    else:
        newvisited = visited + [current]
        # visited.append(current)
        for edge in edges:
            if current in edge:
                letter = edge[1]
                for destination in edges[(current, letter)]:
                    foo = nfsmaccepts(destination, edges, accepting, newvisited)
                    if foo != None:
                        return letter + nfsmaccepts(destination, edges, accepting, newvisited)
        return None
```

This code works just fine. But originally, I had appended current to visited (see 2nd line after the else) and fed that into the recursive call. This, however, threw a syntax error: can't concatenate str with None type object.

Could someone explain why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`NoneType` is the type for the `None` object, which is an object that indicates no value. You cannot add it to lists or other objects.

Since I can't see more code, what is probably happening is that `current` is not set, hence it has the value `None` and when you try to append it to a list, you get that error.

Assign a default value to `current` and then run your code using append. It should work.